# Can several virtual Desktops be active at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, macros, virtual-desktop

Let's say I create a virtual desktop on windows 10 to execute a macro and always mine stuff within a game, could I use a second virtual desktop to surf the web or would that pause the first virtual desktop? Or would the macros mouse and key movements be executed at the wrong virtual desktop?
Is there in general a better solution than running a complete new virtual PC in the background with virtual box (which is  how I solved it until now)?

Comment: Why not just try it out and let us know? Sounds like an interesting idea. Can your macros target a particular virtual desktop? (since you mentioned it can target a particular virtual PC / window in the background)

Comment: @Darius sounds more like he just setup a VM with that automation contained within. But as you said it should be rather easy to just test this. My expectation would be that it won't work.

Comment: Applications will always run in the background, but if your macro is setup to act as a keyboard input, it will act on the current application instead of the background game

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple Virtual Desktops at the same time. That basically is the idea of a virutal desktop, so an app keeps working even if its not visible on the screen.

However, when another virtual desktop is used, the location of the application is either moved off the screen to a virtual location and its button is hidden from the taskbar, or the entire desktop is virtually really large and only the viewport is changed. This is different per program/method used.

Running a virtual PC is always a better solution unless you do not really need macro stuff.

Alternatively, consider getting a cheap second monitor and put your stuff on there. The monitor itself does not have to be powered on if the monitor uses the VGA port, because that port is always active, but if no monitor is connected, then the port can't figure out what resolution to use, and a maximum of 640x480 is available on that display.

Comment: So if macro usage is a must there is no alternative to using a virtual PC because with a virtual desktop or second monitor the mouse movements would be executed at the wrong desktop (the one is surf the web with)?

Comment: No, second monitor is possible. But not a second monitor and virtual desktop.

Comment: Virtual desktop or real second monitor both result in the macros mouse movements being executed at my active web browsing screen instead of within the game. Seems like virtualization of a whole windows remains the only option.

Comment: @Pisle you cannot use macro's and also work at the same time, unless the macro is well written. For example in program langauges such as vbscript, you can send a keystroke to a program without another program losing focus. But if you use something simple, like auto-hotkey, then you indeed need to virtualize the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Switching between virtual desktops in Windows 10 does not pause the previous desktops.  Also, why not use Hyper-V instead of Virtualbox?  Hyper-V is built into Windows 10.

Comment: How would using hyper-v be different to virtual box?

Comment: Honestly picking a hypervisor really is a matter of personal preference.  Hyper-V is more robust over Virtualbox, and it is native to Windows 10, which is why I would use it.  Virtualbox is great, but is mean for personal use and testing, not for production, which means it is fine for what you need a hypervisor for.  

With all of that said, I wouldn't use any hypervisor for what you are trying to do.  You'll be using valuable resources running the additional OS and applications.  All you need, in this situation at least, are virtual desktops.